# Unknown category Moodle

Tags: moodle

Sometimes for any reason, the moodle shows the message **unknown category** and you can't do anything. Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I entered the database and deleted the last record on the table **mdl_course**, because it was the last action that I did. After this, I  entered to moodle site normally. Don't forget to remember what was the last action you did.